# MinGW: How to link without debugging information?

Tags: mingw

I just compiled some existing programs (Windows 32-bit) again and was shocked about the file sizes:

File size of EXE file, compiled with ...

- ... GCC 4.5.0: 34.431 Bytes
- ... GCC 10.2.0: 259.648 Bytes

Investigating the problem, I found out that the EXE file generated by GCC 10.2.0 contains a lot of useless sections:

About 170 K are occupied by sections with debugging information although I compiled my project without debugging information (-g0).

How can I build a project using MinGW without having all this useless data blowing up the resulting EXE file?

Is writing an own linker script the only possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `-g0` you should also strip the binaries (.exe and .dll files) either by linking with the `-s` flag, or running the `strip` command on the binary files.